# Is there a way to Tweak Windows 10 memory management (compression store)?

Tags: windows-10, memory

**Is there a way to Tweak Windows 10 memory management (compression store) ?**

if YES how can i do it (i am willing to try registry or .DLL hack)

[Details on how windows 10 memory management works](https://tweakhound.com/2015/08/20/windows-10-memory-compression/)

Comment: Solution might depend on what purpose you are following.

Comment: I want the OS memory consumption to be under 1GIG or limit it to 1GIG

Comment: so that I have enough RAM to host virtual apps

Comment: what do you want to tweak? What are are HW specs? How much memory does your Windows now use?

Comment: roughly eats up 3Gigs out of 4gigs on a lenovo Z51-70

Comment: post pictures of RAMMap (if you use Build 10240, for 10586 it fails to run), taskmgr->performance->Memory and ResMon->Memory

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/1032578/476112

Comment: required screenshot posted in above link